# There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end-of-input

Tags: ruby, terminal, rvm

Can someone help me? I am getting this error when I try to run rails server.
[terminal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sFdB.png)

My gemfiles are as such [gemfiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbgwH.png)

Thank you very much!

Comment: You are missing a single quote in ruby '2.2.3'

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb your comment should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a single quote in the ruby line

[image: Missing quote]

make it:

```
ruby '2.2.3'
```